# Creating 'Item Fulfilment' record based on 'Sales Order' using Netsuite PHP API and SuiteScript

Tags: php, netsuite, suitescript

I am having issues creating a 'Item Fulfillment' record based on 'Sales Order' using the following code.

```
$objx = array();
$objx = new InitializeRecord();
$objx->type = "itemFulfillment";
$objx->reference->type = "salesOrder";
$objx->reference->internalId = 7793877; // ID of sales order
$request = new InitializeListRequest();
$request->initializeRecord = $objx;
$response = $service->initializeList($request);
```

However the following error message is given :

```
[code] => VALID_LINE_ITEM_REQD
[message] => You must have at least one valid line item for this transaction.
[type] => ERROR
```

Ive used other examples online and always seem to end up with the same error message. I have Advanced Inventory Management enabled in Netsuite.

Update 16/04/2019 :

Had a look into suitescript for the first time and managed to put together some code as a test to transform sales order into item fulfillment using nlapiTransformRecord. However, getting the same error message with this also.

```
var soId = nlapiGetRecordId();
var ifRec = nlapiTransformRecord('salesorder', soId, 'itemfulfillment');
var lcounttwo = ifRec.getLineItemCount('item');
for (var i = 1; i <= lcounttwo; i++){
   ifRec.selectLineItem('item', i);
}
nlapiSubmitRecord(ifRec);
```

Comment: I think you have issue in setting up `$service` variable. GO through this documentation once and check [link](https://github.com/ryanwinchester/netsuite-php)

Comment: Sadly i think that's all ok because i've not had any issues with the $service variable in regards to creating sales order or even creating a cash sales based on a sales order.

Comment: Does the target sales order have any fulfillable lines?

Comment: The sales order has a line item with FulFilled 0 and Quantity 1.

Comment: Fufillable May also include stock being available or committed and the sales order approved. An easy check is can you fulfill the order from the UI?

Comment: Yes i can fulfill by the UI. I just did another test now to re-confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure about the PHP aspect of this but in Java this would be done as follows. Note that the first step is to use the `initialize` call to get the item fulfillment record and then you save it normally. The step of marking each line as fulfillable (`itemReceive`)is common to SuiteTalk and Suitescript.

```
ReadResponse initFF = nsClient.getPort().initialize(new InitializeRecord(InitializeType.itemFulfillment, new InitializeRef(null, InitializeRefType.salesOrder, soId, null), null));
ItemFulfillment ff = (ItemFulfillment)initFF.getRecord();
        ItemFulfillment ff = (ItemFulfillment)initFF.getRecord();
for(ItemFulfillmentItem ffItem : ff.getItemList().getItem()){
    ffItem.setItemReceive(Boolean.TRUE);
}
ff.setShipStatus(ItemFulfillmentShipStatus._shipped);
System.err.println("adding fulfillment");

WriteResponse ffResp = nsClient.getPort().add(ff);
if(!ffResp.getStatus().isIsSuccess()){
    System.err.println(nsClient.getStatusDetails(ffResp.getStatus()));
    fail("Unable to add item fulfillment");
}
```

So the call you are making seems wrong. If you were using the NS supplied PHPtoolkit  you'd be doing:

```
$service->initialize($objx);
```

The corresponding Suitescript would require that you go through the item lines and set the column value itemreceive to true. so in your loop `ifRec.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'itemreceive', 'T');`

Some much older .php I wrote looks like the following and appears to have worked without the itemReceive part. Though it still retrieves a fulfillment record from the initialize call before attempting to submit the fulfillment:

```
    $initRefFields = array('internalId' => $soId, 'type' => 'salesOrder');

    $initRef = new nsComplexObject('InitializeRef');
    $initRef -> setFields($initRefFields);

    $initRecFields = array('reference' => $initRef, 'type' => 'itemFulfillment');

    $initRec = new nsComplexObject('InitializeRecord');
    $initRec -> setFields($initRecFields);

    $readReponse = $nsClient -> initialize($initRec);

    if($readReponse -> isSuccess) {

        $itemFulfillment = $readReponse -> record;
... manipulate lines
        $addResponse = $nsClient -> add($itemFulfillment);
    }
```

Comment: Using Initialize rather InitializeList with $request variable being passed yields the exact same message. If I change $request to $objx i get error stating $objx must be of type InitializeRequest. Ive noticed others with same problem, also with Advanced Inventory Management and PHP toolkit, maybe its just not possible? I wonder if the same can be achieved with suitescript, although i've never used that.